# How to see more realtime logs when using spark-submit?

Tags: apache-spark, logging, pyspark, submit

I am using 'spark-submit' with configuration file and package option and it is taking very long time to run..

How to 'TURN-ON' more logging (in realtime) so that can see where is the bottleneck (e.g. maybe a request to specific server is being made where I do not have access etc.)..

I would ideally want to see everything - from which libraries are being loaded to which request and to which server is being made.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you can see all relevant information either on the [Spark UI](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#web-interfaces) for currently running jobs (usually, this service is reachable at port 4040 of your driver) or (if your system has one) on the [Spark History Server](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#viewing-after-the-fact).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below parameters when you are using Spark on YARN.

```
--driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.error=true" --verbose
```

Or

You can always do the below to get logs from YARN

Use the following command format to view all logs of a particular type for a running application:

```
yarn logs -applicationId <Application ID> -log_files <log_file_type>
```

For example, to view only the stderr error logs:

```
yarn logs -applicationId <Application ID> -log_files stderr
```

The -logFiles option also supports Java regular expressions, so the following format would return all types of log files:

```
yarn logs -applicationId <Application ID> -log_files .*
```